# Euler equation, Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory

My question is: Prove the following:

$$e^{
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{i}t & \omega_{i}t \\
-\omega_{i}t & \sigma_{i}t  \\
\end{bmatrix}}
 = 
e^{\sigma_{i}t}
{\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega_{i}t) & \sin (\omega_{i}t) \\
-\sin(\omega_{i}t) & \cos(\omega_{i}t)  \\
\end{bmatrix}} $$

Thanks in advance, wonderful community of stackexchange.

Comment: my questions is what have you tried ?

Comment: Function evaluation can be easier if you can put your matrix on some canonical form for example diagonal form. Maybe that is possible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an direct answer. Just follow the definitions as @Kwin mentions.

[image]

Comment: [OT] May I ask you a question? How did you type that?

Comment: Xournal, a drawing program for linux to make notes. This was an assignment which I made for university.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Write 
$$
\pmatrix{
\sigma_{i}t & \omega_{i}t \\
-\omega_{i}t & \sigma_{i}t } = \underbrace{\sigma_{i}t \pmatrix{1 &0\\0&1}}_A + \underbrace{\omega_{i}t \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}}_B
$$
Now, note that $AB = BA$, which means that $\exp(A + B) = \exp(A) \exp(B)$.  $\exp(A)$ and $\exp(B)$ can both be nicely computed using the power series definition.